# How to priorities or condition over other conditions mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query which is using sub queries.

```
SELECT t.id FROM subjects t 
where t.topic_id IN (13,11) 
  AND t.id  not in (select subject_id 
                    from user_visited_subjects uvs
                    where uvs.user_id = 3 )  
  OR t.id in (select subject_id
              from user_subject_suggestions uss 
              where uss.user_id = 3 )  
limit 10
```

I want to give priority or conditions means sql should check if there is any record in query

```
OR t.id in (select subject_id from user_subject_suggestions uss where uss.user_id = 3 )
```

then check other conditions.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put parenthesis around them?

Comment: Can you give some sample data? It is unclear what you mean by "give priority". Is it a parenthesis problem (so you currently, without the limit, get the wrong rows as and/or is not mixing as you want it to) or do you mean that the rows that fulfill the first condition (=are more important?) should be ordered infront of the other (for which you will need an `order by`).

Answer (score 0):

Just use parentheses.

Example:

```
SELECT t.id FROM subjects t 
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT subject_id FROM user_subject_suggestions uss WHERE uss.user_id = 3 )
    OR (t.topic_id IN (13,11) 
        AND t.id  NOT IN (SELECT subject_id FROM user_visited_subjects uvs WHERE uvs.user_id = 3 ))
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks , I am testing it.

Comment: Sorry, Still "or" condition doesn't have priority , if there is any result in OR sub query it should display but its not happening .

Comment: Sorry, but the question is a bit unclear :(  So you want to check if `t.id` is in `user_subject_suggestions` OR (`topic_id IN (13,11)` AND `tid` is in `user_visited_subjects`)? I updated my answer.